# Having both EPS and PNG in the same document

Tags: graphics, eps, png

I am using style files from this [link](http://www.rsj.or.jp/advanced_e/submission) for Latex in WinEdt 7.0.

When including figures, If I use **pdflatex** or **PDFTexify** for compiling it doesn't recognize **EPS** files :

```
! LaTeX Error: Unknown graphics extension: .eps.
```

and If I use **Latex** or **Texify** for compiling it doesn't recognize **PNG** files:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
```

Is there any way to include both formats using this style?

An example of the tex file:

```
\documentclass{tADR2e}
\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\maketitle
\section{Module}

\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics{img/1/work1} % the png file
\caption{The process.}
\label{diagram1}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics{img/2/work2} % the eps file
\caption{The process.}
\label{diagram2}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

compiling this tex gives the following error:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `img/2/work2' not found.
```

although there is no extension for the figures and they are even in different folders.

```
>>pdflatex --version

MiKTeX-pdfTeX 2.9.4307 (1.40.12) (MiKTeX 2.9)
Copyright (C) 1982 D. E. Knuth, (C) 1996-2006 Han The Thanh
TeX is a trademark of the American Mathematical Society.
```

The \listfile log can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/y0tsEZ6w).

Comment: You should normally not include file extensions: call different files different things. Using pdfLaTeX with a modern TeX system will then auto-convert from EPS to PDF, allowing PNG inclusion as well.

Comment: 'Doesn't solve the problem' doesn't really tell me much. Did you (1) remove file extensions in your TeX file (2) Renate the two _different_ files so the 'root names' are not the same, (3) run pdfLaTeX? If so, what does `pdflatex --version` at the command line give?

Comment: updated the question with answer.

Comment: OK, it should work with a recent MiKTeX. Please add `\listfiles` to your input, run pdfLaTeX and edit in the `.log` file to the question.

Comment: Your MWE compiles fine over here with the mentioned .cls file. I have `pdfTeX 3.1415926` (TeX Live 2013).

Comment: Actually if I put pdflatex in command-line I get: 'This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-1.40.12 (MiKTeX 2.9)' which seems to be the same version as you have. but If I give it pdflatex --version it gives what I reported in the question!